# Github won't let me remove sensitive data

Tags: git, github

I have a file I want to erase from my repo history. I've run the command on local repo: `git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch faultyfiles.json' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`
But when I want to push that to github, I'm asked for a pull first. And when I pull, you guessed it, the faulty files come back from `origin`. How do I get out of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `git push -f` to force it, without pulling.  Note that this command is somewhat dangerous, and should not be used without thought.

Comment: yep I had to --force it. was shaking a bit, but that's what I needed ;)